# Behaviors of default initialization on struct fields

Tags: c++

When code is written like that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ID {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

int main() {
    ID a;

    cout << (long)(a.name) << endl;
    cout << a.age << endl;
    // cout << (a.name == nullptr) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
0
0
```

However, when it's written like that:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ID {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

int main() {
    ID a;

    cout << (long)(a.name) << endl;
    cout << a.age << endl;
    cout << (a.name == nullptr) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result seem strange:

```
140735032148552
1545300144
0
```

How could these 2 versions vary greatly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Defining a local variable will not initialize it, the contents of the structure will be indeterminate, and using it will lead to said UB.

Comment: Note: It's possible that the memory which is used by the struct will have been zero-initialized at one point (and if you're lucky it still is). But that's actually just bad luck (bad, because if you have zero initialized memory you probably wont be stumbling over this mistake. But somebody else certainly will if you wait long enough)

Comment: If you wish to have zero-initialized structure, there are few ways to get it, ex.: `memset(&a, 0, sizeof(ID) );`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Thank you! Pileborg, Daniel and pstanisz. Your answer and comments are of great help to me.

My confusion came from a paragraph in "C++ Primer". In case anybody else has the same confusion, I write my understanding here.

Original word:

> Under the new standard, we can supply an in-class initializer for a data member. When we create objects, the in-class initializers will be used to initialize the data members. Members without an initializer are default initialized (§ 2.2.1, p. 43). Thus, when we define Sales_data objects, units_sold and revenue will be initialized to 0, and bookNo will be initialized to the empty string.
>
> -- "C++ Primer 5th edition"

I had thought that fields in a struct follow the same default initialization rule as global variable (i.e. initialized to their zero values). But it actually follows the same rule as local variables in a funtion, which is:

1. All primitive built-in types are not initialized, leaving them to be random value originally in memory.
2. Class types are initialized using their default constructor. If there is not a default constructor, the struct containing the class type cannot be created (proper parameters required).